# Only show prime numbers in a NumericUpDown control

Tags: c#, winforms, numbers, primes

```
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //my numeric up down var name is numrsa1//
    }

    static bool IsPrimeNumber(int value)
    {
        bool result = true;

        for (int i = 2; i < value; i++)
        {
            if (value % i == 0)
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (value <= 1)
            result = false;

        return result;
    }`
```

I would like to know if there's a way to show in the Numeric Up Down only prime numbers. I'm trying to make a crypthography work for university and I need give only prime numbers options for the user.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please read here how to ask questions. You should specify what have you done and what are you missing so the others can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ashkan I didn't nothing yeat because I don't know what type o logic I need to use.

Comment: by up down you mean descending order?

Comment: you can store the previous value in the tag property and then check if it is lower or higher then calculate the next prime number and set the value of the numeric up down

Comment: No, but you can use a listbox and a prepopulated prime numbers source.

Comment: First off you should probably just use a Prime Seive, but if you just want to test for prime, you only need to 1. Check up to the SQRT.  2. check if its even first and then only check the odd numbers for division. 3. The last check you are doing at the end you should probably do first

Comment: Use a DomainUpDown control instead.  It's like a NumericUpDown, but you can populate with your own collection, which in your case, would be just prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are asking for functionality that is *similar* to the `NumericUpDown` control, but with different behavior, then I suggest you create a new control `PrimeNumberUpDown` that *extends* the `NumericUpDown` control.

Here is a quick version I through together.  I tested that it works for up/down using the mouse or arrow keys, and entering a number into the text box.  You may want to test it more exhaustively if it's going into anything critical.

Paste this code into a new file (updating the namespace accordingly), compile, then you should see a `PrimeNumberUpDown` control appear in your toolbox so you can use it like any other Windows Forms control.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class PrimeNumberUpDown : NumericUpDown
    {
        private int _value;

        public PrimeNumberUpDown()
        {
            // Make sure default value is prime
            if (!IsPrime((int)Value))
                SetNextPrimeValue();
            _value = (int)Value;
        }

        public override void DownButton()
        {
            SetNextPrimeValue();
        }

        public override void UpButton()
        {
            SetPreviousPrimeValue();
        }

        private void SetNextPrimeValue()
        {
            int newValue = (int)Value;
            while (newValue <= Maximum)
            {
                if (IsPrime(++newValue))
                {
                    if (newValue <= Maximum)
                    {
                        Value = newValue;
                        _value = newValue;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetPreviousPrimeValue()
        {
            int newValue = (int)Value;
            while (newValue >= Minimum)
            {
                if (IsPrime(--newValue))
                {
                    if (newValue >= Minimum)
                    {
                        Value = newValue;
                        _value = newValue;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void ValidateEditText()
        {
            if (_value == 0)
            {
                base.ValidateEditText();
                return;
            }

            int newValue;
            if (int.TryParse(Text, out newValue) && IsPrime(newValue) && newValue >= Minimum && newValue <= Maximum)
            {
                _value = newValue;
                base.ValidateEditText();
            }
            else
            {
                ChangingText = true;
                Text = _value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }

        private static bool IsPrime(int number)
        {
            if (number == 1) return false;
            if (number == 2) return true;
            if (number % 2 == 0) return false;

            int boundary = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number));

            for (int i = 3; i <= boundary; i += 2)
            {
                if (number % i == 0) return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you have it :) it will show only prime numbers

```
private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //suposing you have this code
    int numrsa1 = (int)this.numericUpDown2.Value;

    //or add the rest 8 lines to your code
    if (IsPrimeNumber(numrsa1))
    {
        numericUpDown2.Value = numrsa1;
    }
    else
    {
        numericUpDown2.UpButton();
    }
}
```

`//the rest is your code without changes, I am using you function declaration IsPrimeNumber()` in order to validate the number and print the result there. It will go up for the moment and show only a prime number by increasing in ascending order the value of the control.

This is a very simple solution I could test fast enough to post asap :)